# What is the advantage of using anonymous pl/sql block over the normal stored procedure?

Tags: plsql, plsqldeveloper

Can anyone give some information about the advantages and disadvantages of using an anonymous pl/sql block over a stored procedure? When should we use an anonymous block?

Answer (score 0):

You must use an anonymous block when you, call a procedure from an sql*plus, precompiler, oci, etc. app. In all other cases, the only real advantages of an anonymous block, is the fact that you do not need to declare it in advance and you can specify it dynamically.

Procedures, function and packages on the other side allow you to structure an application, are precompiled and therefore syntactically correct by definition except for the dynamic SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Anonymous block is used when you don't want to create a procedure or function in database but you want to apply all pl/sql logic/ want to use pl/sql language for code construct. you need anonymous block to call any database object; output can be printed using dbms_output.put_line. basically it will give you all control of pl/sql language.